# How to get the dynamic cell height that is calculated by iOS auto layout?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a simply UITableViewController with dynamic cell height using multi-line UILabel.  I let iOS auto layout does the calculation for me.  So I didn't have to calculate any height myself.  But now, I want to take whatever height iOS auto layout returns to me and increment it by N.  I'm not sure how to go about doing it without reinventing the wheel in `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
CGRect frame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"row height : %f", frame.size.height);
```

so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect frame = cell.frame;
    CGFLoat heightOfRow = frame.size.height;
    return heightOfRow +n;

}
```

EDIT:

It seems you can't do anything with the height until the table is setup, and the only way to solve this problem is to let the table load and then reload it with the new heights...can do it like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     CGRect frame = cell.frame;
     self.heightOfRow = frame.size.height;
     [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{

    return self.heightOfRow +n;

}
```

You may need to stick a BOOL in this so it only does it once.

Comment: Calling [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] seems to end up in a infinite loop because it would end up calling heightForRowAtIndexPath, which calls rectForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Calling tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath() returns nil. heightForRowAtIndexPath is called after tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) and the cell is not really in the tableView yet while all the cells are still being constructed and their sizes are being calculated.  heightForRowAtIndexPath looks to me it's something called before auto layout happens.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Like you said seems you have to allow the table to setup first, let it do the auto layout then calculate the height and reload the data. Unfortunately seems you have to do that reload.

Comment: You might be better doing dynamic height using the auto layout and not in code, maybe this well hep: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Answer (score -2):

I will update my answer with code.

Please find the code below to be used in iOS8

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Luke - I posted a link to youtube but i got it down voted due to sharing a link and not an actual code.

Comment: @Jassi Yep I can see it, so you should have also included the link to the Github repo too, and added some code from it etc to help the question asker. If you do not want to fix this answer then I'd recommend you delete it, because it may attract more downvotes / get voted for deletion otherwise. (my comment was auto posted after seeing this answer appear in one of the post moderation queues)

Comment: Can i give a link from raywenderlich as it is a very big code. Cant put all the code here.

Comment: You can provide a link, but you can't provide *only* a link: You need to provide enough content for the answer still to be of some help even if the link breaks in the future.

Comment: Setting estimagedRowHeight and rowHeight are not what I'm looking for. I already did that part because, as I stated in the question, I already let auto layout does the sizing for me.